# Blazor Custom element not working with Blazor Server and Angular

Tags: websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side, custom-element, .net-7.0

I created an app using Angular with ASP.Net core project template to work with Blazor Custom Elements in Blazor Server. I created the component and registered it as a custom element as suggested in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-custom-elements). I added the proxy config and other changes for angular by referring to ring the asp labs [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/BlazorCustomElements).

When I ran the sample I faced the below issue and the custom element is not working as expected.
[image: Angular sample output and the error message]

```
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
blazor.server.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:44476/_blazor?id=gxW6SsA09YwNC2qyxoqguw' failed: 
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-01-13T18:51:43.964Z] Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-01-13T18:51:43.967Z] Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
```

Here is my sample [repo](https://github.com/NavinVinayagam/AngularWithCore)

It seems I am missing something, how can I resolve the error and get the custom element working?

As Astrid suggested in the comments, I am attaching the details of all the codes I have added to the angular with a core project template.

Added Custom elements NuGet in AngularWithCore.csProj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="7.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Created Counter.razor and added under AngularWithCore/Pages/Counter.razor

```
<h1>@Title</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<p>Increment amount: @IncrementAmount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = "Blazor Counter";
    [Parameter] public int? IncrementAmount { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount += IncrementAmount.GetValueOrDefault(1);
    }
}
```

Added Blazorhub, razor pages, server-side blazor in the Program.cs and registered Counter as custom element

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("my-blazor-counter");
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

Updated the Proxy config in client app

```
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:6937';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/_content",
      "/_framework",
      "/_blazor"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    ws: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Added Blazor script Index.HTML in the client app

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularWithCore</title>
  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements.lib.module.js"></script>
  <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</head>
```

Added Blazor custom element in the angular page

```
<h1>Blazor Counter </h1>
<my-blazor-counter increment-amount=4></my-blazor-counter>
```

Comment: Did you enabled websockets and if you're using multiple instances, did you enabled sticky sessions?

Take a look at this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43175

Comment: Actually, I am facing an error in the local host where a regular Blazor server app is working fine.  I tried adding sessions, but it didn't help me out.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your current (not working) code in code snippets in your question post. The content in your repo may change over time, and could in the future potentially not be relevant for this question anymore (or cause confusion about what the problem actually was).

Comment: Sure @AstridE. , I have added the images to the question as you suggested. Actually, I created the repo in GitHub just for this question, as I trying to learn about custom elements by creating local samples.

Comment: Having your code in a repo is great! I just wanted to point out that any future changes to that repo will potentially make the source code there inconsistent with this question post. Regarding proper inclusion of code snippets: Please refer to [this answer to the question 'Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Offering reproducible code examples makes it easier for people to try to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the keep-alive header from the proxy did the trick and resolved the issue.
Thanks for the solution provided by the dotnet team in [issue - 46091](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46091) .

I have updated my [repo](https://github.com/NavinVinayagam/AngularWithCore) with the solution.

Here is the updated proxy config which resolved the issue.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/_content",
      "/_framework",
      "/_blazor",
    ],
    proxyTimeout: 3000,
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  },
  {
    context: [
      "/_blazor"
    ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    ws: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
  }
];
```